# Why are retracts of connected manifolds embedded submanifolds?

Tags: manifolds, smooth-manifolds, submanifold

I'm now working on this exercise:

> Let $f: M \rightarrow M$ be a smooth map on a smooth, **connected** manifold $M$, satisfying $f \circ f = f$, then prove that $f(M)$ is an embedded manifold of $M$.

I have viewed many existed posts discussing this exercise, especially this one:[Proving $f(X)$ is a submanifold](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/252522/proving-fx-is-a-submanifold?rq=1). In this post, the question provides hints as follows:

> - (1) $\mathrm{rk}_p f \leq \mathrm{rk}_{f(p)} f$ for all $p \in M$ ;
> - (2) The rank of $f$ is constant along $f(M)$;
> - (3) The rank of $f$ is constant in an open neighbourhood of $f(M)$;
> - (4) Show that $f(M)$ is a submanifold when the above holds (using the constant rank theorem).

I'm managed to prove the first two points. (And I shall post a detailed answer on the above link later)

**My question is**: how to prove the third and the fourth point?

**My attempts for (3)**: I have actually proved a stronger result than (2), namely the rank of $f$ on $f(M)$ is $\max_{p \in M} \mathrm{rk}_p f$. (See [rank of function on connected manifold](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1043680/rank-of-function-on-connected-manifold?rq=1) for this.) So I'm trying to show that for any $p \in f(M)$, there exists an open neighborhood $U_p$ in $M$, such that $\mathrm{rk}_q f \geq r$ for any $q \in U_p$. Also by (1), we see that $\mathrm{rk}_q f \leq \mathrm{rk}_{f(q)} f = r$. Combining these two together, $\mathrm{rk}_q f = r$ for any $q \in U_p$. Then taking the union of $U_p$ over $p \in f(M)$, we are done for (3). BUT, **how to find such a desired $U_p$?** I'm thinking of using the connectness of $f(M)$.  [P.S. This method is adapted from [P. W. Michor, Topics in Differential Geometry](http://www.mat.univie.ac.at/%7Emichor/dgbook.pdf), Section 1.15.]

**My attempt for (4)**: I don't know how to apply the *constant rank theorem* here. My understanding of the *constant rank theorem* is:

> Let $f: M^m \rightarrow N^n$ be a smooth map between smooth manifolds $M^m$ and $N^n$. For $q \in N^n$, if there exists an open neighborhood $U$ of $f^{-1}(q)$, such that $\mathrm{rank} f$ is a constant on $U$, then $f^{-1}(q)$ is an embedded submanifold of $M^m$ (if the fiber $f^{-1}(q)$ is not empty).

Here in my exercise, I think I should consider $f$ (in my exercise) as $f$ (in the above theorem), $M$ as $M^m$ and $M$ as $N^n$. Then how can I write $f(M)$ as a fiber of a point $q \in M$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For (3):

Assuming you allready know that the rank of $f$ is maximal on $f(M)$:

> The rank
> $$\text{rk}\, f:M\to\mathbb Z$$
> is lower-semicontinous and hence locally only can  jump up.

This follows from the lower-semicontinuity of the rank of $n\times n$-matrices. So the set

$$\{x\in M:\text{rk}_xf=r\}=\{x\in M:\text{rk}_xf>r-\frac 12\}$$
is open and hence an open neighborhood of $f(M)$.

For (4):

Let $x_0\in f(M)$. Then by the constant rank Theorem there are charts $(U,\phi)$, $(V,\psi)$ about $x_0=f(x_0)$ with $f(U)\subseteq V$ and

$$\psi\circ f\circ \phi^{-1}(x_1,\dots,x_n)=(x_1,\dots,x_r,0,\dots,0)$$

and by shrinking $V$ one can assume $\psi(f(U))=\psi(V)\cap(\mathbb R^r\times\{0\}$).

Now set $W=U\cap V$, which is an open neighborhood of $x_0$. $f\circ f=f$ implies $W\cap f(M)=W\cap f(U)$ and $\psi$  injective implies $\psi(W\cap f(U))=\psi(W)\cap\psi(f(U))$, so

$$\psi(W\cap f(M))=
\psi(W\cap f(U))=
\psi(W)\cap \psi(V)\cap (\mathbb R^r\times\{0\}))=
\psi(W)\cap(\mathbb R^r\times\{0\})$$

which shows that $f(M)$ is a submanifold of $M$.

Comment: Thank you for your great answer!

Answer (score 1):

For (3) maybe this will help
[How to prove that the rank of a matrix is a lower semi-continuous function?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1913394/how-to-prove-that-the-rank-of-a-matrix-is-a-lower-semi-continuous-function/1914865)

For (4) Try this version of the constant rank theorem http://www.math.toronto.edu/mgualt/MAT1300/week3.pdf.

Comment: The links provided are of great help!! I have tried to prove that rank function has certain "continuity" property but only obtained that rank is continuous on $f(M)$. [By noting that the jacobian of $f$ on $f(M)$ is idempotent matrix and hence its rank equals to its trace.] I have never imagined that there're broader results. And the same for the constant rank theorem! Thank you so much!